# Main menu does not display on pages with a specific path

Tags: 7, routes, blocks

Having a really frustrating problem with my Drupal site. On pages that have a specific path the main menu block does not load.

For example I have the path..

- meet-our-derms/bios
- meet-our-derms/test

The main menu block does not appear on either of those pages. As soon as I change the path to something like *meet-our-derms2/bios*, the menu appears.

I have the menu block set to appear on all pages, all content types, and I don't believe there are any add-on modules that would have any control over this.

Is there any other place that I should look? Any ideas as to why this is happening on only that path?

Comment: Hi,

Have you switched themes, say to bartik, to test if it's a custom theme causing the issue?

Bartik, and other contrib themes, usually, print the main menu directly in page.tpl.php, rather than as a block in a page region.

Comment: Are the two pages using any specific template files that doesn't have region in which you have configured your blocks to show up??